# How to put array as field in json. Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a json field in PostgreSQL:
`{"cpu": 88, "hdd": 1200, "ram": 2048}`.

I want to add a new array field: `spec_os_max = string_to_array('RHEL 7.9,RHEL 8.*,Ubuntu 18.04,ESXi 7.0', ',')`

I'm trying this:

```
update public.resources r
set params = jsonb_set(params::jsonb, '{spec_os_max}', string_to_array('RHEL 7.9,RHEL 8.*,Ubuntu 18.04,ESXi 7.0', ','))
where id in (122561, 122560);
```

I have the following errors: `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Can anybody explain how to do this? Thank You.

Comment: You are mixing up PostgreSQL arrays and JSON arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As in [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html)
you need to pass to jsonb_set 3 arguments : target jsonb, path text[] and new value as jsonb. You can made it like  this:

```
with resources as (
  select '{"abc": 1, "def": "some text"}'::jsonb as params
)
select jsonb_set(params, array['spec_os_max'], array_to_json(string_to_array('RHEL 7.9,RHEL 8.*,Ubuntu 18.04,ESXi 7.0', ','))::jsonb)
from resources
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update t 
set properties = jsonb_set(properties, '{spec}', jsonb_build_array('aa', 'bb'));
```